# How can we implement Priority Queue using HashMap(using key-value approach) in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can we implement Priority Queue using HashMap in Rust?

```
pub trait PRQ<Element> {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn insert(&mut self, element: Element, p: u64);
    fn peek(&self) -> Option<Element>;
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<Element>;
}

pub struct PRQImpl(HashMap<Vec<u8>, Vec<u8>>);

impl PRQ<Vec<u8>> for PRQImpl {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self(HashMap::new())
    }

    fn insert(&mut self, element: Vec<u8>, p: u64) {
        //
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
        //
    }

    fn peek(&self) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
        //
    }
}
```

```
////Tests

let mut q = PRQImpl::new();

q.insert(vec![1], 10);
q.insert(vec![2], 8);
q.insert(vec![3], 4);
q.insert(vec![4], 7);
assert_eq!(q.pop(), Some(vec![1]));
```

I can not change `PRQImpl` definition neither the method definition. I know HashMap is not ordered and this is not the right approach to implement Priority Queue.

Can someone please guide me on how I can implement Priority Queue with the above definition?

Comment: If this is a school exercise, feel free to tell your professor I believe it sucks. This is not the right data structure for the task.

Comment: you can use 3 backticks to create code block for code.

Comment: I'm perplexed, you need to store the priority `p` *somewhere*, but if the only options in `PRQImpl` are a `Vec<u8>` and a `Vec<u8>` (and one of those will store the `Element`), there's not really a place to store a `u64`... unless you split it into bytes, but that seems even more far-out than making a hashmap based priority queue in the first place.

Comment: Can think of HashMap of Priority queue(s) not a Priority queue out of HashMap :( First work on whiteboard or paper then see what concrete data structures are suitable.

Comment: I guess you could use a reserved key (e.g. `vec![]`) and treat the value as a binary heap? But then since your keys have are arbitrary length, it would get really tricky to store them in the heap. What is the reason for these odd restrictions? I second @orlp, this exercise sucks lol